# useContext working not working with nested component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-context

I am trying to refactor an app to use `useContext` but have hit a snag and cannot figure out what is happening.

Using the latest version of everything, running Next.js.

The way things are structured is that every page is wrapped in `<Layout>` and *some* pages are also wrapped in `<Fund>`, nested under `<Layout>`.

I have global context that is set in `_app.js` and passed to `Layout` where it is rendered.  This works fine, the `aTest` context variable that I define in `pages/_app.js` renders on `Layout` and shows on all pages.

Then I have fund-specific context that is set in `components/Fund.js` and loaded in on `pages/fund/index.js` (and subsequent other pages).

This does not work.  The `anotherTest` context variable that I define in `/components/Fund.js` is *not* showing in `/pages/fund/index.js` even though the return statement there is wrapped in the `<Fund>` component (which I assume should hold and pass on the context).

I think I have maybe got my child/parent order mixed up for the non-working scenario but by brain is fried.  Any tips?

Stripped back, the basic code is:

```
/components/
   - UserContext.js
   - FundContext.js
   - Layout.js
   - Fund.js

/pages/
   - _app.js
   - index.js
   - /fund/
      - index.js
```

Both the `/components/*Context.js` files are the same bar the names declared in them:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const FundContext = createContext();
export default FundContext;
```

and

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const UserContext = createContext();
export default UserContext;
```

In `/pages/_app.js` I am doing:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserContext from '../components/UserContext';
...

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   ...
   return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{
         aTest: "This is a test"
    }}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
   )
}

export default MyApp
```

In `/components/Layout.js` I am doing:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from './UserContext';
const Layout = ({children}) => {    

   let {aTest} = useContext(UserContext);

   return (
      <main>
         <h1>{aTest}</h1>
         {children}
      </main>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

In `/components/Fund.js` I am doing:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from './FundContext';
const Fund = ({children}) => {    

   return (
      <main>
         <h1>{aTest}</h1>
            <FundContext.Provider value={{ anotherTest: "Just another test" }}>
            {children}
         </FundContext.Provider>
      </main>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

In `/pages/fund/index.js` I am doing:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import FundContext from '../../components/FundContext';
...

export default function App () { 

   let {anotherTest} = useContext(FundContext);
   
   return (
      <Fund>
         {anotherTest}
      </Fund>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your useContext hook is called in the global scope on `/pages/fund/index.js`. Moving the hook to the scope of the component should fix the issue.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import FundContext from '../../components/FundContext';
...

export default function App () {
   let {anotherTest} = useContext(FundContext);
 
   return (
      <Fund>
         {anotherTest}
      </Fund>
   )
```

Also, I do not see a `FundContext.Provider` anywhere in the provided code, which means that calls to `useContext(FundContext)` will not work as intended. If it is not present, make sure a wrap the consumers of `FundContext` with it.

#### EDIT (OP updated the question):

`useContext(FundContext)` is being used above `FundContext.Provider` in the component tree.

```
  |_App (useContext(FundContext))
     |_Fund
         |_FundContext.Provider
                    |_{anotherTest}
```

Consider moving `FundContext.Provider` above the App component, or pass a component similar to the following one as a child to `Fund`:

```
const AnotherTest = () => {
  let {anotherTest} = useContext(FundContext);

  return (
      <>
         {anotherTest}
      </>
   )
}
```

`/pages/fund/index.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import FundContext from '../../components/FundContext';
...
export default function App () {
   return (
      <Fund>
         <AnotherTest />
      </Fund>
   )
}
```

Comment: Sorry some typos on my part, I have updated `fund.js` now to include the `FundContext.Provider`.  I also moved the `useContext` to inside the component and it's not fixed it.  I tried console logging `useContext(fundContext)` and its returns `undefined`.

Comment: You are using the `useContext` hook above the provider in the component tree. I will update the answer to reflect your changes

Comment: Argh sorry! `fund` is not even be using the `useContext` hook, only establishing the data for the enew context `FundContext`, which is then to be passed to its children `/pages/fund/index.js`.  

The example code should be correct now (still not working)

Comment: Answer should be accurate now